# Изображение в анонсе новсти из RSS Drupal 7 или 8

Tags: изображения, drupal, rss

Добрый день,

На Joomla есть компонент http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/simple-rss-feed-reader,  который позволяет отобразить и анонс новости и картинку если такая поставляется RSS, как сделать точно такое на Drupal 7 или 8 ?

Анонс новости, дата и автор - выводятся очень просто посредством настройки модуля Aggregator и затем ложим соответвующий блок в нужный регион и все заработало ... но там нет изображений ну собственно ничего. т.е. стандартные блоки друпала отстали лет на 10-ть ?

Как можно получить в анонсе и текст и изображение новости.

я использую только стандартные средства DRUPAL 7(8) Т.е. создаю записи в Конфигурация\ Веб службы \ Сборщике RSS, там добавляю новую ленту, например http://www.vesti.ru/vesti.rss и получаю только название новости, в блоке последние новости - вести(блок создается автоматически): например выглядит так:

> ```
> Путин подписал закон, упрощающий получение ВНЖ для беженцев из Украины
> В турецкой провинции Диярбакыр в результате теракта пострадали 10 военных
> В Риме перед турецким посольством протестующие написали "Эрдоган террорист"
> ```

и никаких картинок, хотя в RSS они есть это видно в браузере.

Comment: если изображение вставлено в начало текста оно итак вылезет в анонс, если же к каждой новости по картинке - создаете доп.поле при помощи cck и views'ом выводите картинку как вам душа пожелает. Rss можете тоже создать вьюсом.

Comment: добрый день, у меня никакие изображения не отображаются, пока я использую только стандартные средства DRUPAL 7(8) Т.е. создаю записи в Конфигурация\ Веб службы \ Сборщике RSS, там добавляю новую ленту, например http://www.vesti.ru/vesti.rss и получаю только название новости, в блоке последние новости - вести(блок создается автоматически):

Comment: ну так на джумлу вы компонент устанавливаете, а на друпале хотите добиться того же без установки доп.модулей?